# NodeJS and express, ENOENT on view file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got a weird trouble with my nodeJS app since I refactored it.

The app starts well, API answers correctly but when I try to go to /, I get this error : `Error: ENOENT, stat '/views/index.html'` in my browser.

I now use this folder tree :

- project

  - front

    - views

      - index.html
  - bower_components
  - app
  - node

    - server.js

And here is the content of my *server.js* file :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');
var nconf = require('nconf');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../front'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../node_modules'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../bower_components'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());

server.listen(8081);

(...) // some code to define API routes

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/views/index.html');
});
```

I tried to comment `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../front'));` and to call the view using '/front/views/index.html' but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sean3z suggested, I tried to change my sendfile declaration and got another error (Forbidden, sendStream error).

Finally I managed to make it work by changing my static files definition : 
`app.use('/front', express.static(__dirname + '/../front'));`

And by modifying the sendFile : `res.sendfile('front/views/index.html');`

Strangely, nodeJS understands (but not me :) ) and call the right file at the right place. I just need to correct my calls in the differents file to be ok.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

[`ENOENT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) means `Error NO ENTry` which ultimately means it's not able to find your file.

> int ENOENT
>
> No such file or directory. This is a "file doesn't exist"
>   error for ordinary files that are referenced in contexts where they
>   are expected to already exist.

Your server is attempting to send a file from the root directory of your machine (`/views/index.html`). You'll probably need to adjust this to fit your file structure.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/../font/views/index.html');
});
```

Comment: @Sean3z : strangely when I try what you suggested, I get another error : rror: `Forbidden
   at SendStream.error (/home/marc/tennis/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:228:16)
   at SendStream.pipe (/home/marc/tennis/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:423:19)
   at ServerResponse.res.sendfile (/home/marc/tennis/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:409:8)
   at /home/marc/tennis/node/server.js:423:9`

Comment: @Sean3z : and when I try `res.sendfile('front/views/index.html');` everything's working (except my ANgularJS linked but I can understand it). The real question is "Why does node understand a path without a / although the folder is elsewhere ? "

Comment: @MarcDelerue because without the leading `/` the path is relative to the application. With the leading `/` it's absolute to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you missed to set your `views` folder.

```
app.set('views', 'MY_DIR_PATH');
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem better. I kind of resolved it changing my static declaration...

Comment: you can also use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/');`